# Java String с интами (задача взорвала мне мозг)

Tags: строки, substring

Скажите пожалуйста, реально ли определенному charAt присвоить другое значение, в виде char или инт ?

```
String s = "10210";
s.charAt(0) = '0';
```

Не дает присвоить ни инт ни char (((

Вопрос только про это, но если кому интересно, мой вопрос -  часть решения задачи о том, что бы выводить строку вида:    10000 + 200 + 10 . Решал двумя циклами бегая по подстроке.
**По этой задаче прошу не давать готвый код, можем обсудить только в виде псевдо кода.**

//спустя пару часов ...
Почти получилось, но вот на выходе строка:

2000000 + 100000 + 500 + 1 **+**

как же убрать этот последний + ???

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String s = "2100501";


                for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
                        if (Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i)) != 0){
                                String s2 = s.substring(i+1, s.length());
                                StringBuilder s3 = new StringBuilder(s2);
                                for (int x = 0; x<s3.length(); x++){
                                        s3.setCharAt(x, '0');
                                }
                                System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
                                System.out.print(s3 + " + ");
                        }
                }
        }


}
```

Comment: "Не дает присвоить ни инт ни char (((" --- а ты читал описание метода charAt?

Comment: ["Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: "реально ли определенному charAt присвоить другое значение" --- можно изменить значение и изменённый результат снова положить в ту же переменную

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, Вы уже вполне самостоятельно решили задачу.

Если оставшийся вопрос - только в том, как убрать последний плюс- посмотрите на условие цикла.

У Вас может получиться что то вроде:

```
            public class Main {
                    public static void main(String[] args) {
                            String s = "2100501";


                            for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
                                    if (Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i)) != 0){
                                            String s2 = s.substring(i+1, s.length());
                                            StringBuilder s3 = new StringBuilder(s2);
                                            for (int x = 0; x<s3.length(); x++){
                                                    s3.setCharAt(x, '0');
                                            }
                                            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
                                            System.out.print(s3);
                                            if ( i<s.length()-1 )
                                                    System.out.print(" + ");
                                    }
                            }
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Красота, спасибо !!!